# Full subcategory and inclusion functor

Tags: category-theory

I have the suspicion that if $A$ is a subcategory of $B$, then the inclusion functor $A \rightarrow B$ is full. Is this right?

Comment: I think the easiest possible counterexample is the group homomorphism $\{e\} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2$ considered as a functor of one-object categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $A$ be the category of groups and $B$ be the category whose objects are groups but whose arrows are functions (not necessarily homomorphisms). Then there are set-theoretic maps (functions) between groups which are not group homomorphisms, hence the functor is not surjective on the $\operatorname{Hom}$ sets, which is what it means for a subcategory to be full.

Comment: Thanks. I was not paying attention to the "between groups which are not group homomorphisms" part.

Comment: @Kup The category of groups is not a subcategory of the category of sets. So it's not a counterexample to your question.

Comment: @MakotoKato http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcategory

Comment: @BrettFrankel Different groups can be defined on the same underlying set.

Comment: @MakotoKato Right you are. Silly me.

Comment: OK, it's a bit more artificial now, but that should take care of the issue. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 4):

Let $B$ be a category.
We define a category $A$ as follows.
The class of objects of $A$ is the same as that of $B$.
The morphisms of $A$ are monomorphisms of $B$.
Then $A$ is a subcategoy of $B$.
The inclusion functor $A \rightarrow B$ is not necessarily full.
For example, if $B$ is the category of sets, $A \rightarrow B$ is not full.